# Algebra involving square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation:  $${\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}mg - R = m({\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}a)$$

I then change it to the following:$$a={\frac{\sqrt2 mg - 2R}{\sqrt2 m}}\space \space \space Equation\space 1$$

Now this is all good and well ( or so I believe), then I have the next equation: $$R Sin(45)=7ma$$

$$R={\frac{7\sqrt2}{2}}ma \space \space \space Equation\space 2$$

Now I let $m=1$ then sub Equation 2 into Equation 1, then I get:

$$a={\frac{1}{14\sqrt2}}g$$

the answer I should get is $${\frac{1}{15}}g$$

Could someone tell me when I went wrong because I am stumpted.

Comment: $\sin (45°) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, you transformed equation 2 as if it were $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: so it should be: $g-\sqrt2 R = ma$, I wrote $sin(45)={\frac{2}{\sqrt2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for $\,x>0\;,\;\;\frac{\sqrt x}x=\frac1{\sqrt x}\;$ , so you can go

$$\frac{mg}{\sqrt2}-R=\frac{ma}{\sqrt2}\implies a=g-\frac{R\sqrt2}{m}$$

In eq. 2 you have

$$R\sin45^\circ=7ma\implies R=7\sqrt2\,ma$$

and substituting in eq. 1 we get

$$a=g-7\sqrt2\,ma\frac{\sqrt2}m=g-14a\implies a=\frac1{15}g$$

The mistake is in eq. 2: you must multiply, and not divide, by $\,\sqrt2\;$  when clearing out $\,R\,$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin 45 =\frac {\sqrt 2} 2$ you need $R=\frac {14}{\sqrt 2}ma=7 \sqrt 2 ma$ about half way down.

I should do this bit first and then substitute for $R$ in the first equation. You can then cancel $m\neq 0$ (not "let $m=1$") and cancel $\sqrt 2$ - then you have straight linear equation to solve for $a$ in terms of $g$.